# How to save and reuse all settings for a keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**The question:**

With a keras model (partly) specified such as this:

```
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
```

Is it in any way possible to save all details in the model for later use?

---

**The details:**

I've been following an example from [machinelearningmastery.com](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/) and trying to modify and add traits / arguments of the model such as

- activation='relu'
- activation='sigmoid'
- metrics=['accuracy']

And as the question suggests, I'd like to store model settings for later use.
I understand that these arguments are parts of different functions, but shouldn't it be possible all the same?

**What I've tried:**

**1.** `model.save()` and `model.load()`

Only returns

> AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'load'

**2.** `model.get_config()`

Here I've been able to find some of the settings such as:

> [{'class_name': 'Dense',   'config': {'activation': 'relu',

But I haven't found a way to load that config as a standalone model, and more often than not, I can't seem to find all settings.

**3.** I've also checked other posts such as K[eras - Reuse weights from a previous layer - converting to keras tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564579/keras-reuse-weights-from-a-previous-layer-converting-to-keras-tensor), but all aspects of the model don't seem to be covered.

Any suggestions?

Comment: quick google gave me the following result: https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/ - here, you store the model config as JSON and retrieve it later on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying `model.load()` try using `load_model()` provided by keras to load the model you saved using `model.save()`

```
from keras.models import load_model   
load_model(filepath)
```

Also you can save the model as json using `model.to_json()` and load from json using `model_from_json()`

You can see more ways to save and load a model in Keras Documentation 
[here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)

Comment: This is only part of the answer since the settings of fitting are lost

Answer (score 2):

`model.save()` will do the trick to save the model, to load it use `from keras.models import load_model` and use `model=load_model(model_name)` to load the model